# How to Show Date with AM/PM instead of specifying time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way can we convert Datetime to (dd/MM/yyyy AM/PM) format 
for example 18/03/2014 AM in SQL

Comment: DeateTime columns do not have any specific format. You can specify the format when you convert them to text either on the server or the client side. Why do this on the server though?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It's for query

Comment: **Why** are you doing this?  If you're planning on grouping by this, you probably want to do it by range, as calling a formatting function would invalidate the use of an index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MYSQL:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d/%m/%Y %p')
```

For SQL SERVER

```
SELECT convert(varchar(20), GetDate(), 103) + ' ' + substring(convert(varchar(30), GetDate(), 9), 25, 2);
```

For Postgres:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'dd/mm/yyyy AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft SQL Server you can use

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 103) 
+ CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 12 THEN ' AM' 
                                           ELSE ' PM' END
```